# AJAX Contact Form Reloads Page but Doesn't Send Email

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hi like the title say my code seems to reload the page when hitting the send button but never actually sends the email. I've tried and read everything I could and nothing is allowing it to work properly. I would sincerely appreciate the help.

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.dropotron.js"></script>
<script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/skel-panels.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/init.js"></script>
<script src="js/contact.js"></script>
<noscript>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skel-noscript.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-noscript.css" />
</noscript>


          <!-- Contact Form-->
          <div class="content style4 featured">
       <div class="container small">
       <form id="contact" form method="post">

        <div class="row half">
         <div class="6u"><input type="text" class="text" name="name" id ="name" placeholder="Name" /></div>
           <div class="6u"><input type="text" class="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" id="email"/></div>
      </div>

<div class="row half">
    <div class="12u"><textarea name="text" placeholder="Message" id="message"></textarea></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="12u">
        <ul class="actions">
            <li><input type="submit" class="button" value="Send Message" /></li>
            <li><input type="reset" class="button alt" value="Clear Form" /></li>
   <p class="success" style="display:none">Your message has been sent successfully.</p>
            <p class="error" style="display:none">E-mail must be valid and message must   be longer than 100 characters.</p>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>

</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    // Email Submit
    // Note: filter_var() requires PHP >= 5.2.0
    if ( isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['message']) &&      filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
        // detect & prevent header injections
        $test = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:|to:)/i";
        foreach ( $_POST as $key => $val ) {
            if (preg_match( $test, $val ))
            exit;
        }

        //send email
        mail( "test@gmail.com", "Contact Form: ".$_POST['name'], $_POST['text'], "From:" .      $_POST['email'] );
    }
?>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#contact').submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var name = $("#name").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
var message = $("#message").val();
//var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&message=' + message;

$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "mail.php",
    data : {name:name,email:email,message:message},
    cache : false,
    success : function() {              
        $("#contact").fadeOut(300);
        $("#notice").fadeIn(400);
    }
});
return false;
```

});

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did u try just posting to mail.php and see if the mail is going <form id="contact" form method="post" action="mail.php"> let me know if this works, then we can check the ajax issue.

Comment: Hi, just added that to the server side php and the emails are coming threw, but obviously going to the unwanted /php page as well.

Comment: Check my answer that might help !!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your email function works well in the AJAX part you need to use [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Also noticed in the mail.php you have this

```
if ( isset($_POST['email']) 
&& isset($_POST['name']) && 
**isset($_POST['text'])** && 
filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
}
```

this will fail `isset($_POST['text'])` since there is no post element I suppose it should be `isset($_POST['message'])`

Also your form elements are missing the ids please add them as

```
<!-- Contact Form-->
<div class="content style4 featured">
<div class="container small">
    <form id="contact" form method="post">

    <div class="row half">
        <div class="6u"><input type="text" class="text" name="name" id ="name" placeholder="Name" /></div>
        <div class="6u"><input type="text" class="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" id="email"/></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row half">
        <div class="12u"><textarea name="text" placeholder="Message" id="message"></textarea></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="12u">
            <ul class="actions">
                <li><input type="submit" class="button" value="Send Message" /></li>
                <li><input type="reset" class="button alt" value="Clear Form" /></li>
<p class="success" style="display:none">Your message has been sent successfully.</p>
                <p class="error" style="display:none">E-mail must be valid and message must be longer than 100 characters.</p>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>

    </form>
</div>
</div>


<script>
    $('#contact').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var message = $("#message").val();
        //var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&message=' + message;

        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "mail.php",
            data : {name:name,email:email,message:message},
            cache : false,
            success : function() {              
                $("#contact").fadeOut(300);
                $("#notice").fadeIn(400);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

    </script>
```

I have just tested and it worked for me.

Comment: hmmm,  didi u try alert(name+ '' + email+' '+message) inside the function after getting the values and see if its getting.

Comment: Sorry for the noobness but I'm not sure where your asking me to add that part of the code?

Comment: add this line alert(name+ '' + email+' '+message); inside the JS just above $.ajax({ and submit, see what u get.

Comment: Check my updated answer, you have to add the "id" in the form element as well as I had an error the correct way is e.preventDefault(); check the code it should work now.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for the help. I just edited the original code above and it should be as your saying correct? On my side its still not working but at the top is what is on my side.

Comment: did you add the script inside <script></script> , you JS needs to be inside the above script.

Comment: The JS needs to be in the head of the html? Or in my .JS form the entire code needs to be inside <script></script>?

Comment: No add them below the page dont add them on the top.

Comment: So is there any need to have <script src="js/contact.js"></script>
in the head?

Comment: Okay so 2 things. I got an email but it was a blank email? Also the entire form disappeared after I hit send?

Comment: You need to add some success message here 
success :function(){}   regarding blank email  you need to change $_POST['text'] to $_POST['message'] inside the mail()

Answer (score 1):

Can you modify your function, i think it is not getting called at all.

```
$('#contact').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var message = $("#message").val();
    //var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&message=' + message;

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "mail.php",
        data : {name:name,email:email,message:message},
        cache : false,
        success : function() {              
            $("#contact").fadeOut(300);
            $("#notice").fadeIn(400);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I got an email but it was a blank email? Also the entire form disappeared after I hit send?

Comment: Your mail is empty because you are setting message as $_POST['text'], change it to $_POST['message'] in your php mail function. Your form disappears because you are using fadeOut in your success function. You have a success message in your HTML before error, set its id as 'notice'. So when ajax call is success, mail is sent, form disappears and notice appears.

Answer (score 0):

Does your mail() function actually work by itself?  Like can you send some mail using that function?  Also, the PHP isset function will take mixed arguments like so...

PHP:

```
if(isset( $_POST['email'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['text'], filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $rules = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:|to:)/i";
    foreach( $_POST as $key => value ) {
        if(preg_match($rules, $value)) 
          exit;
    } //end of foreach
} //end of if
```

Comment: Hi I tried the PHP all on its own and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

your submit button is doing a form post, u need to stop the default behavior of that button and call your method performing ajax on click of submit button.

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: So I just need to add this into my head, correct?

<script>
$( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $( "<div>" )
    .append( "default " + event.type + " prevented" )
    .appendTo( "#log" );
});
</script>

Answer (score 0):

In JS you are accessing the values by id but you are giving id's just do the thing give id's for input tags i.e. name, email, message

```
<div class="6u"><input type="text" class="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" /></div>
<div class="6u"><input type="text" class="text" placeholder="Email" id="email" name="email" /></div>
<div
```

class="12u">

give your dataString as

var dataString = {name:name,email:email,message:message};

for more set header in mail i.e.

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
```

$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: ' . "\r\n";

`mail( "test@gmail.com", "Contact Form: ".$_POST['name'], $_POST['text'], "From:" .$_POST['email'] ,$headers);`

Answer (score 0):

better if you write it just before where the body tag is closing instead of writing in head. and above code will get executed whenever you click on an anchor tag. so be specific like this. `<body>  <!-- just before body tags closes--><script> $('a.buttonClassName').click(function(e){e.preventDefault(); $("<div>default"+e.type+ "prevented</div>").appendTo("#log") })</script></body>`

Comment: Add it in. Form is send but emails are blank now?